# finding prime number using the square root method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was able to write a function for the prime number using this way

```
def isprime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if num % i == 0:
                return False
        return True

%timeit [i for i in range(1000) if isprime(i)]
7.94 ms ± 273 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Then I found that there's an even faster way to write this using the square root but I couldn't understand the working of this. **Can anyone explain this code in easier terms and why it works?**

```
def isprime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, int(num ** 0.5) + 1):
            if num % i == 0:
                return False
        return True

%timeit [i for i in range(1000) if isprime(i)]    
1.94 ms ± 54.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

If this is a duplicate please let me know I will delete it instantly.

Comment: it's even faster if you start from 3 and only do odd numbers `for i in range(3, int(num**0.5)+1, 2): ...`

Comment: You never have to test any factors larger than the square root of the number, because you would have already found the number not to be prime if it was divisible by a number larger than that (because the other factor would be smaller than the square root in that circumstance).

Comment: Because if `x * y == num`, at least one of `x` or `y` is less than or equal to the square root of `num`.

Comment: If this is python 3 it doesn't matter, but in python 2.x, `range` creates a list and iterates it and `xrange` creates a generator, so using xrange will be much faster.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer the degenerate case is when `num` *is* a prime, you can stop checking earlier in 2.x *and* 3.x with this analysis. In fact, as the list is created either way in 2.x, I'd expect the gain in 3.x to be *larger*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think that in 2.x, even with range you will create a shorter list for the second case and thus allocate less memory and it will be faster.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think that you just explained in one line what took me four paragraphs. Nicely done. I once taught this very method to an introductory programming class. Had I thought of your phrasing, it might have saved the class some time!

Comment: This is a question for [math.SE], pretty sure. Not as much a duplicate. I kind of like the answer accepted here a little better than [the answers there though](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1343171/13219). You also asked the question better than the person there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is best explained by example. Suppose that you wish to know whether 143 is prime. Do you really need to try to divide by 142, 141, 140, 139, and so on? Obviously, none of those divides 143; they're too big.

But see:

- 143 %  2 = 1
- 143 %  3 = 2
- 143 %  5 = 3
- 143 %  7 = 3
- 143 % 11 = 0

Apparently, 11 divides 143. Not prime.

Now let's investigate 145. Is 145 prime?

- 145 %  2 = 1
- 145 %  3 = 1
- 145 %  5 = 0

Apparently, 5 divides 145. Not prime. Now consider, we *could* have tried

- 145 % 29 = 0

That would have worked because 145 = 5*29, but it wasn't necessary to try a factor as large as 29. The 5 sufficed.

So think about this. If a composite number n = a*b has two factors, a and b, suppose that b > sqrt(n). In that case, it must be the case that a < sqrt(n), for, were it not so, then a*b could not equal n. Indeed, were it not so, then a*b would be *larger* than n, implying that a*b were not a proper factorization of n.

All you need to do is to find the value of the smaller factor. The smaller factor is less than, or is at most equal to, the square root. If no factor less than or equal to the square root is found, it follows that the number under investigation is prime.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to check factors up to a number's square root to determine whether the number is prime -- any factor greater than its square root would have to be paired with one less than its square root, and you've already checked them.

This allows the second implementation to finish its loop *much* earlier (e.g. you only need to test 2..31 to determine that 997 is prime, rather than 2..996 as in the first implementation).

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def is_prime(n):
    for i in (3,int(n**0.5)+2):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
        else:
            return True

print(is_prime(25))
```

Even this code posing same issue, here 25 should be non_prime but its posing prime.

Comment: This code tests for divisibility by 3, and returns either False or True based solely on that result.  No other potential factors get tested.